# How to append a div to an iframe's parent?

Tags: javascript, iframe

I would like to create a div in the parent window of an iframe (the main window). I never thought I would look so hard for this.

I tried the following:

```
parent.document.createElement('div')
window.parent.document.createElement('div')
window.parent.document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].createElement('div')
```

the properties of the iframe are as follow:

```
scrolling: 'no',
width: 400,
height: 125,
frameborder: 0,
sandbox: 'allow-forms allow-popups allow-same-origin allow-scripts allow-top-navigation allow-modals allow-popups-to-escape-sandbox'
```

I want to clarify that the script is called inside the iframe as I understand it may not have been clear before.

Answer (score 0):

You need following steps to modify the dom tree as desired:

1. Get the parent of the iframe
2. Create div element
3. Insert new created div before iframe

Here is the code (it works fine for me):

```
 var iframe = document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[0];
 var iframeParent = iframe.parentElement;
 var div = document.createElement('div');
 iframeParent.insertBefore(div, iframe);
```

Comment: `var iframe = document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[0]; console.log('IFRAME', iframe);` returns `IFRAME undefined` as this is called from the iframe itself.